# does gfortran append underscores... error linking Fortran and C

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile [FormCalc 9.9](http://www.feynarts.de/formcalc) on a MacOS 10.10.5.

Compilation consists in running a bash script on terminal. I redirect both `stdout` and `sterr` to a log file, but this is all the output I get:

```
$ ./compile 
Compiling for system type MacOSX-x86-64
cp -p ./bin/MacOSX-x86-64/* MacOSX-x86-64/
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -Wextra  -m64 -o MacOSX-x86-64/ToForm ./FormCalc/ToForm.c
./FormCalc/ToForm.c:72:9: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
        __attribute__ ((fallthrough));
      ^
>
1 warning generated.
strip MacOSX-x86-64/ToForm
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -Wextra  -m64 -o MacOSX-x86-64/ToFortran ./FormCalc/ToFortran.c
strip MacOSX-x86-64/ToFortran
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -Wextra  -m64 -o MacOSX-x86-64/ToC ./FormCalc/ToC.c
strip MacOSX-x86-64/ToC
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -Wall -Wextra  -m64 -o MacOSX-x86-64/reorder ./tools/reorder.c
strip MacOSX-x86-64/reorder
looking for gcc... /usr/bin/clang
looking for g++... /usr/bin/clang++
looking for fortran... /usr/local/bin/gfortran
extracting the Fortran libraries... ok
does gfortran append underscores... error linking Fortran and C
```

How can I get more information about the linking error?

Comment: Isn't there an additional log file created?

Comment: See the sources of `./compile` script and find what it does. The messages look like autoconf.

Comment: Re Vladimir F
There's no log file created (in ./compile 's dir or elsewhere) as far as I can see.

Comment: Re Kamil Cuk
I wanted to attach the ```./compile``` script, but I don't seem to be able to.
It's available from [this link](http://www.feynarts.de/formcalc/FormCalc-9.9.tar.gz).

Comment: gfortran does append underscores by default.  You could read the fine manual to see how to change it, however, the correct way is to use bind(C,name= ...).   The  autoscript; should take care of that and other things, so it is a sign that something went wrong with the detection of system type.